# Build a GIT Repository from parts of other Repository

Tags: git, module

Is it possible to create a fresh new GIT repository with parts of another GIT repository?

Let me explain. I have a repository moderately big with several modules. This "system" can be used entirely or modularly. But take out from the main repository all required files for each module is not always an easy task.

So I would like know if I can create some small repositories, let's say one for each module with all their dependencies AND keep them synchronized to the main repository.

Conceptually, it would be a submodule, but unless I'm wrong, this is not what this feature was made for.

Answer (score 0):

Git submodules let you to move entire subdirectory into separate repository and link to exact commit in there.

If your modules overlap, like you have few shared directories and each module has few files in each of these dirs, then you need to redesign your modules. Git submodules are nice when you have dir hiearchy like this:

```
 |-- application
 |   |-- class
 |   `-- some stuff
 |
 `-- plugins
     |-- first
     |   |-- class
     |   `-- some stuff
     |-- second
     |   |-- class
     |   `-- some stuff
     `-- third
         |-- class
         `-- some stuff
```

Where `plugins/first`, `plugins/second`, and `plugins/third` are submodule root directories.

Comment: Well, so I think it's not possible because even the most part of these modules are structured like you said, not all the required files are. For example, my **HTTP Request** Class is under _/HTTP_, but requires a superclass stored in _/Core_

Comment: Dependencies between submodules are not a problem. You simply need all dependencies installed. The location of all files from one plugin must be exclusively in one subdirectory, which is git submodule, what these files use is not important.

Comment: And how would it works, for example, if three submodules has the same dependency and I need to fix something in this dependency? Will all the references be updated automatically? And if one project uses two modules with the same dependency, wouldn't cause problems to require them both with the chosen language?

Comment: There are no references between plugins in Git. Only root repository has references to commits in all submodules. So when you update something, you create new commit in root repository. Also, there is no plugin dependency checking -- you need to do that using some other tool and it depends on your application.